# Symfony getting mapped entities with statement (where clause)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I got a understanding question.

I got 2 mapped Entities

```
class news
{   
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->newsgroups = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Unite\NewsBundle\Entity\newsgroup",     inversedBy="news")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="news_to_newsgroup")
     **/
     protected $newsgroups;
....
}
```

And

```
class newsgroup
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->news = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Unite\NewsBundle\Entity\news", mappedBy="newsgroups", cascade={"detach"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"undate" = "DESC"})
     **/
    protected $news;
....
}
```

My question: 
how can i get all news which are active and between date x and y WHERE newsgroup = 'x' 
when i'm using my newsgroup object (function getNews())

```
/**
 * Gets the groups granted to the user.
 *
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getNews()
{
    return $this->news ?: $this->news = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Is it realy necessary to go through each news with a foreach and check if my conditions are true?

Thanks a lot my friends for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to get news by your conditions. Query will be smth like this

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('n')
            ->innerJoin('n.newsgoup', 'ng')
            ->where('ng.id > :newsGroupId')
            ->where('ng.undate BETWEEN :monday AND :sunday')
            ->setParameter('newsGroupId', '1')
            ->setParameter('monday', '2016-01-02')
            ->setParameter('sunday', '2016-02-17')
            ->getQuery();
    $news = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i was thinking about this way. I thought there is another way given from the doctrine manytomany mapping. So its just like normal msqli commands with doctrine. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Ha it worked :D   - innerJoin maps to newsgroup automatically because of the manytomany mapping. Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) class to filter the collection.

You may create an extra method in your entity:

```
public function getFilteredNews()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where('isActive', true)
        ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->between(
            'createdAt', 
            '2016-02-20', 
            '2016-02-25'
        ));

    return $this->getNews()->matching($criteria);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [filter](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html#_filter) method from `ArrayCollection` or create a repository for your entity and fetch the data using [QueryBuilder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) (as suggested by Anna).

Comment: Okay so i think this is the way i was looking for. I'll try your solution. What do you think is the better way for sustainable and espacially powerful  development?

Comment: Yeah, please specify more details next time, like version you are using etc. :) I would recommend QueryBuilder custom queries but still, it depends from the use cases.